# Save multiple image in react with a multiple step form

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, multipartform-data, multer

This question is about a problem that happen when i want to save the images + multer + multiple step form and  "react-images-upload" in react;
Can you help me?Thanks!!

This is about a multiple step form in react.

Media  Step:

```
export default function Media({ formData, setFormData }) {

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      foto: [event]
    });
 
  };

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={1}>
       ..
      <Grid container item xs={8} spacing={2}>
        <div className="container">
          <FormControl>
            <ImageUploader
              withIcon={false}
              withPreview={true}
              buttonText="Choose images"
              onChange={handleChange}
              imgExtension={[".jpg", ".gif", ".png", ".gif"]}
              maxFileSize={5242880}
            />
          </FormControl>
        </div>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
```

ProductForm file:

```
function getStepContent(stepIndex) {
    switch (stepIndex) {
      case 0:
        return (
          <Basics
            formData={formData}
            setFormData={setFormData}
 
          />
        );
      case 1:
        return <Price formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />;
      case 2:
        return <Shipping formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />;
      case 3:
        return (
          <Media formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData}   />
        );
    }
  }
 

  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const steps = getSteps();

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };
  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };

  const save = () => {
 
    saveProduct(formData, setFormData, handleReset);
  };
```

```
export async function saveProduct(formData, setFormData, handleReset) {
  const foto =  formData.foto ;
  console.log(foto)
  return await axios({
    method: "post",
 
    url: `${URL}/api/productos`,
    data: formData,
    headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
  })
```

Backend side
(it ' s work except the file upload)

```
router.post('/',upload.array('foto', 10),this.controlador.saveProducts
    );
```

Here is the console.log(event) [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j67wL.jpg)

Thanks very much!

Comment: Where is `formData` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be treating `formData` as a plain object but for posting `multipart/form-data`, you should be using a `FormData` instance.

First, create `formData` as a `ref` so it's not recreated for every render. You can also create a function to pass to your components for adding files

```js
// in ProductForm
const formData = useRef(new FormData());

const addFoto = (file) => {
  formData.current.append("foto", file);
};
```

Now you can pass the `addFoto` function to your components

```html
<Basics addFoto={addFoto} />
```

and use it in your `Media` component

```js
export default function Media({ addFoto }) {

  const handleChange = (file) => {
    addFoto(file);
  };

  // ...
```

Finally, back in your `ProductForm` component, post the data like this

```js
// no custom headers required
axios.post(`${URL}/api/productos`, formData.current);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it help me a lot. For the backend, i have change  this line too   `router.post('/', upload.any(), this.controlador.saveProducts);` Regards!

Comment: @Jennifer that doesn't seem necessary